# Avoid Deadlock wtih Popen and stdout = PIPE in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, deadlock, popen

I am executing a shell script using Popen. I am also using **stdout=PIPE** to capture the output.The code is

```
pipe = Popen('acbd.sh', shell=True, stdout = PIPE)
while pipe.poll() is None:
        time.sleep(0.5)
text = pipe.communicate()[0]
if pipe.returncode == 0:
    print "File executed"
```

According to documentation using poll with **stdout = PIPE** can lead to deadlock. Also **communicate()** can be used to solve this problem. I have used communicate() here.

Will my code lead to deadlock with communicate too or am I using communicate usage wrong?

Also I have an alternate in subprocess.check_output but I would prefer to use Popen and record the output with same.

Comment: BTW, don't use `shell=True` here. You can execute an external process that's a shell script without it. Basically, `shell=True` makes your first line equivalent to `pipe = Popen(['sh', '-c', 'abcd.sh'], stdout=PIPE)` -- but if your `abcd.sh` is executable (has `+x` permissions and a valid shebang), then you don't *need* `sh` to be explicitly invoked to run it, and in fact, you're having *two* shells spawned when you only need one (the first one running the `sh -c`, the second one invoked by the shebang for `abcd.sh`).

Comment: Also, see [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for guidance on Python code-formatting convention -- spaces surrounding `=` are correct on an assignment, but not when passing a keyword argument value or establishing a default value in an argument list -- so it's `pipe = Popen(...)`, but `stdout=PIPE`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the guidance. I guess `studout = PIPE` must be a correct way to put the argument. I will read further.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am getting an error if I am giving `shell=false` command. It says "No such file or directory"

Comment: If you have such a difference, presumably your command is something more complicated than `abcd.sh` (with no arguments) -- as in that case, `abcd.sh` needs to be an executable file that exists in your path whether `shell=True` or `shell=False` (the only exception being the case where you're depending on your shell treating a non-executable file as a script, which isn't guaranteed or reliable behavior). Regardless: If you provided your *real* command, I could describe how to make it work with `shell=False`.

Comment: ...and to be clear: If this *is* the non-executable script case, btw, then the best-practice fix is to actually make the script executable and give it a legitimate shebang.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - My script does have arguments. The basically appends data in a file so inputs are provided.

Comment: In that case, `pipe = Popen(['scriptname', 'arg1', 'arg2'], stdout=PIPE)` is the format. This is much, *much* safer than trying to use string concatenation to form your arguments, since it means that someone sneaking `$(rm -rf $HOME)` (or something similarly destructive) into a filename being processed won't cause that string to run as a command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffyThanks for the suggestion. I will surely test that out. Also when the script finishes what happens to the subprocess when `shell=True`. I tried both to kill and terminate process but the it errored out saying **no such process**. Does that mean the process kills itself?

Comment: In normal cases (where no self-daemonization has taken place), `communicate()` won't return until your child processes have exited. I'm not sure that's what you're asking, though -- if you have something reproducible and contrary to documentation as you understand it, it might be appropriate to ask another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can deadlock, because of these two lines:

```
while pipe.poll() is None:
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Take them out; there's no need for them here. `communicate()` will wait for the subprocess to close its FDs (as happens on exit) as it is; when you add a loop yourself, *and don't read until after that loop completes*, then your program can be stuck indefinitely trying to write contents which can't be written until `communicate()` causes the other side of the pipeline to start reading.

---

As background: The POSIX specification for the `write()` call does not make any guarantees about the amount of data that can be written to a FIFO before it will block, or that this amount of data will be consistent *even within a given system* -- thus, the safe thing is to assume that any write to a FIFO is *always* allowed to block unless there's a reader actively consuming that data.

Comment: My motive with while loop and statements was that code should not move forward until the process completes. If I use `text = pipe.communicate()[0]` will this wait until my process completes and save the shell script output in text variable?

Comment: Yes, `pipe.communicate()` will wait until the process completes. Yes, `text = pipe.communicate()[0]` will save stdout of that completed process in the variable named `text`.

Comment: according to the document, the "while pipe.poll() is None..." is used to do something else when the process is running. but why here it will be in a dead loop here?